# CSS Grid with multiple same-width auto columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve the following layout using CSS Grids. It's a basic **key-value display** with three pairs in one row.

```
| foo       | value 1      | bar       | value 2      | baz       | value 3      |
 xxxxxxxxxxx                xxxxxxxxxxx                xxxxxxxxxxx
| qux       | value 4      | quux      | value 5      | quuuuuuux | value 6      |
 xxxxxxxxxxx                xxxxxxxxxxx                xxxxxxxxxxx
```

The **keys** (`foo`, `bar`, `baz`, ...) are in **auto, but equal width columns**. Note that the second row contains the longest key `quuuuuuux`, defining the width of *all* key columns.

The **values** should use up the remaining grid space equally (`1fr` or similar).

I already tried `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto 1fr);`, but the key columns still have individual widths.

The layout should handle an arbitrary number of key-value pairs.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto 1fr);
  grid-gap: .2em .5em;
}

.key {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #ffcccc;
}

.value {
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="key">foo</div>
  <div class="value">value 1</div>

  <div class="key">bar</div>
  <div class="value">value 2</div>

  <div class="key">baz</div>
  <div class="value">value 3</div>

  <div class="key">qux</div>
  <div class="value">value 4</div>

  <div class="key">quux</div>
  <div class="value">value 5</div>

  <div class="key">quuuuuuux</div>
  <div class="value">value 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just using css or javascript is fine?

Comment: key columns have an auto width, it will adapt to the longest content of each columns and they will be most of the time of different's width. your code works as expected :(.

Comment: @SandrinJoy The solution should be CSS only.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus yeah I know, the snippet is for reference only so the community has a starting point for dabbling around ;)

Comment: To measure the largest column, and set the other key columns accordingly, might require javascript. Unless you're happy to just set all the key columns with a fixed width.

Comment: @Daniel , when we use repeat, the existing properties is reseted after each cycle. So its impossible to do this using grid-column style.And further more, there is table style to get your desired output

Comment: you will always have 6 pairs? or it's dynamic? always 3 in a row or dymanic too?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Updated the question

Comment: @SandrinJoy If you mean ˋdisplay: tableˋ, that won’t make the widths of columns 1, 3 and 5 equal across the entire table